# looping two columns when their time is close to each other by a given threshold value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns in a dataframe named [Timeline and Start] and their type is a timestamp.

I want to write a function that can set a threshold value = 30 seconds, and if the time in the start column is close to any value in the time of the Timeline column by the threshold value, this value from the start column will be moved under the Timeline column.

For example, insert 00:58:26 under 00:11:27 in the same start column if they have the difference in time of the threshold value.

[image]

My code which I tried can only find time similarities as objects, which is not the required task.

```
threshold = 0.8


from difflib import SequenceMatcher
 
def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

 
result_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Timeline", "Start"])
for i, r1 in df1.iterrows():
    for j, r2 in df2.iterrows():
        if similar(r1["Timeline"], r2["Start"]) > threshold:
            result_1.loc[len(result_1.index)] = [r1["Timeline"], r2["Start"]]

print(result_1)
```

The Timeline column is the actual time, while the start column is just a predicted one. I want to move every value from the start column to be below the Timeline column if they have a difference in time of 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The code below determines the difference between timeline and start for each line. If the (absolute) difference is smaller than the threshold value, then the corresponding value from the Start column is inserted below the value of the Timeline column.

```
import pandas as pd

# Our DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=list(range(13)),
    columns=["Timeline", "Start"]
)

# Raw data (HH:MM:ss)
df["Start"] = [
    "00:57:43",
    "00:57:57",
    "00:57:58",
    "00:58:02",
    "00:58:07",
    "00:58:17",
    "00:58:20",
    "00:58:26",
    "01:01:18",
    "01:01:19",
    "01:01:24",
    "01:01:34",
    "01:01:48"
]
# Put the rest of the data into the DataFrame
df.loc[[0, 3, 4, 7, 11], "Timeline"] = [
    "00:10:46",
    "00:10:54",
    "00:11:06",
    "00:11:27",
    "00:12:16"
]

# Converting to timestamps
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

# Difference
df["absdiff"] = pd.DataFrame.abs(
    (df["Timeline"] - df["Start"]).astype("timedelta64[s]"))

# Threshold in seconds
threshold_in_seconds = 2828

# Get all indices where the absolut difference is below the threshold
idx = df[df["absdiff"] < threshold_in_seconds]["Timeline"].index

# Get the "Start" values which will replace the "Timeline" values
values = df["Start"].loc[idx]

# Increase the resulting index by 1 and append an empty row to the dataframe
# to make sure the index will not exceed the length of the dataframe
idx += 1
df = df.append(pd.Series(dtype="object"), ignore_index=True)

# Insert the new values at the index
df.loc[idx, "Timeline"] = values.to_numpy()

# Drop
df.drop(labels=["absdiff"], axis="columns", inplace=True)
```

This code turns this

```
     Timeline               Start
0  2021-12-21 00:10:46 2021-12-21 00:57:43
1                  NaT 2021-12-21 00:57:57
2                  NaT 2021-12-21 00:57:58
3  2021-12-21 00:10:54 2021-12-21 00:58:02
4  2021-12-21 00:11:06 2021-12-21 00:58:07
5                  NaT 2021-12-21 00:58:17
6                  NaT 2021-12-21 00:58:20
7  2021-12-21 00:11:27 2021-12-21 00:58:26
8                  NaT 2021-12-21 01:01:18
9                  NaT 2021-12-21 01:01:19
10                 NaT 2021-12-21 01:01:24
11 2021-12-21 00:12:16 2021-12-21 01:01:34
12                 NaT 2021-12-21 01:01:48
```

into this

```
     Timeline               Start
0  2021-12-21 00:10:46 2021-12-21 00:57:43
1  2021-12-21 00:57:43 2021-12-21 00:57:57
2                  NaT 2021-12-21 00:57:58
3  2021-12-21 00:10:54 2021-12-21 00:58:02
4  2021-12-21 00:11:06 2021-12-21 00:58:07
5  2021-12-21 00:58:07 2021-12-21 00:58:17
6                  NaT 2021-12-21 00:58:20
7  2021-12-21 00:11:27 2021-12-21 00:58:26
8  2021-12-21 00:58:26 2021-12-21 01:01:18
9                  NaT 2021-12-21 01:01:19
10                 NaT 2021-12-21 01:01:24
11 2021-12-21 00:12:16 2021-12-21 01:01:34
12                 NaT 2021-12-21 01:01:48
13                 NaT                 NaT
```

Comment: I used iterrows to compare the start column with all the values in the timeline column, can you write the script so that I can test it if it works? thanks.

Comment: Ok son, just give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: Sure, thank you.

Comment: I only need to move the times from the start column to be below the times in the timeline column in the index if the difference in time is in a threshold of 30 seconds. My dataset is large, so at the end, the timeline column should be filled with a sequential timeline.

Comment: Your code only returns the absdiff in time between each row if found [Timeline and start] which was not the requirement. can you please check my above comment? Thanks.

Comment: With this approch you ll never get a sequential timeline. Pls share one more picture to clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have updated the picture

Comment: @AhmedEwis Il edit my answer. My current code alters the Timeline column and substitues its values with the values from Start if the difference falls below the threshold

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question as required. thanks

Comment: @AhmedEwis I edited my answer accordingly. Pls check if this is what you want.